# Function defined as probability with unknown distribution of parameters

Tags: probability-theory, functions, derivatives

Suppose I define a function $f(A,B,C,D)$ as the probability of $\frac{A}{B}$ being greater than $\frac{C}{D}$. Thus $f(A,B,C,D) = Pr \left(\frac{A}{B}>\frac{C}{D}\right)$. The distributions of $A,B,C,D$ are unknown, we only know that $A,B,C,D \geq 1$.

My intuition is that $f$ is increasing in $A, D$ and decreasing in $B,C$, or $f_A>0$, $f_D>0$ etc. Is it possible to prove this if the distributions are unknown, and if so, how?

Comment: Is every one of $A,B,C,D$ following a fixed (unknown) distribution? If so, isn't $Pr \left(\frac{A}{B}>\frac{C}{D}\right)$ a constant?

Comment: I don't think it's coming from the same distribution (in which case I understand why it would be a constant!). To provide some context, say A is the difference between two (variable) payoffs, B is a cost variable, C is an effort variable etc. (these aren't the actual parameter, just examples). Hope I'm making sense

Comment: I was assuming that $A,B,C,D$ were independent, so I was asking whether each one of them follows a distribution, not necessarily the same one. I shouldn't have made such an assumption though. My question should have been whether the variables $A,B,C,D$ follow an (uknown) [joint probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution). If so, $Pr \left(\frac{A}{B}>\frac{C}{D}\right)$ is a constant - it only depends on which distribution do $A,B,C,D$ follow.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand (although in this case I also assume each variable is independent). I could probably make that assumption that they have some joint probability distribution. Thank you so much for your reply!